# How do I "logout" of parse command line?

Tags: parse-platform, terminal

I am using cloud code, and I have two Parse accounts. I have authorized the first Parse account, but I want to add cloud code to the new Parse account, but whenever I do `Parse add`, it automatically takes me to the list of apps with the parse account I have authorized, how do I pull up the apps from the other account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Parse Github Issues Page](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-cli/issues/52), there is no logout, but you can change the default key you're using by `parse configure accountkey -d`

Hope that helps!